# Looking for a specific food taste description

Tags: single-word-requests

I went through several lists trying to find a word describing a specific food taste to it.

[Like this one.](https://www.kyrene.org/cms/lib2/AZ01001083/Centricity/Domain/1671/Food%20words.pdf)

[Or that one.](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/british/words-used-to-describe-specific-tastes-and-flavours)

I am trying to find an appropriate word for the following taste description:

> With some 'oomph!' to it but delicious / strong but delicious.

In that context, 'oomph' would be like "leaves a strong initial impression on your taste buds, but tastes delicious overall"

What would be the best word fitting that description?

I couldn't find it in lists above.

Comment: Spicy? Strong? Aromatic? You can help by describing the kind of *oomph* you have in mind. Or perhaps it’s just on the tip of your tongue. :)

Comment: @Lawrence Like, leaves a strong initial impression on your taste buds, but tastes delicious overall (e.g afterwards the initial "oomph").

Comment: Please [edit] with some examples. Wasabi? Garlic? Vinegar? Cheese?

Comment: @Lawrence I took another looks at lists. Will "Zesty" fit the description?

Comment: Not if it’s hot chilli peppers you’re thinking of.

Comment: @Lawrence No, not a hot chilli peppers. More like 'savory/strongly delicious, with a hint of 'oomph'' I honestly don't know how else I can describe it.

Comment: What sort of dish has the taste you're trying to describe?

Comment: @KarlG Like a main course dish.

Comment: But what kind? We've got the savory bit, just not the initial flavor burst.

Comment: @KarlG What if we modify it into "strong delicious taste", without a "kick"? It's hard for me to describe it any more than it currently is.

Comment: You haven't given a specific example of a dish. Name a dish that exemplifies what you're talking about—and one that *doesn't* so that it can be contrasted with it. You can't just say *any and every* main course dish. Name a main course dish with "oomph" and one without. (Note that "delicious" is completely subjective, so it doesn't help.)

Comment: @JasonBassford tbh, I never had any particular food in mind when trying to get a description for a flavor. Maybe like, high-grade meat cuisine.

Comment: Consider the Japanese loanword _umami._ In the right phrase it might do the job. In Japanese it literally means _deliciousness_ but it is always used with a more specific meaning in English - the deep savoury taste specific to meats, beef stock, soy sauce, miso, kombu and bonito flakes... and, as an isolate, to monosodium glutamate. In the right phrase, _umami_ might be of some use to you. (It might be too technical - that's what the phrasing would have to counteract.)

Comment: @tmgr I'll probably just stick with Savory. Never thought I would have so much trouble with it.

Comment: Ancient Japanese proverb: _Shimpuru iizu besuto._

Comment: @tmgr what does it mean?

Comment: Sorry! Not  as obvious as I thought. Also not so ancient, and not so Japanese... but they do say it there a lot, and just like that. It's a straight lift from English: _Simple is best._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This vinegar gives the dish ***some kick or pizzazz.***

Oomph is really for energy, kick is for taste.

I don't have any oomph today.

Of course, one can say all sorts of things about food and its gustatory effects. That said, kick is often used. Pizzazz is usually about clothes or decoration(s), but it works with food, too.

"I have it very rarely — only when I want something with a little kick, because even when I order it “not spicy,” I still have trouble eating it. Tom yum is characterized by its distinct hot-and-sour flavor." [kick](https://www.nomadicmatt.com/travel-blogs/the-best-thai-food-you-can-eat/)

Comment: What if we modify description into "strong delicious taste", without a "kick"?

Comment: too similar for a separate answer: "some punch" is also good.

Comment: @VadzimSavenok Whatever.

Comment: As thanks for the effort. Never thought it would end up being so difficult.